# continue the network operation after user go back from calling activity

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm working on a social application, where user can send media, now when user is on the chat activity user select and send a video /photo, we are using retrofit for network operation, we are uploading the attachment with a simple post request, now if user push back before completing the file upload, the file is not uploading to server, now please any one help me to achieve that.

I have tried with a background thread bot not working .

Comment: You can use coroutine ```GlobalScope``` for this but it's not recommended. The recommended way is to use WorkManager as answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using WorkManager?

```
    class MediaUploadWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters)
        : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
    
        override fun doWork(): Result {
            try {
                // Upload your file using Retrofit or any other method.
                // ...
    
                // If the upload is successful
                return Result.success()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // If there's an error, you might want to retry depending on the error
                return Result.retry()
            }
        }

}
```

but first, you have to include dependencies

Whenever you want to start the upload (i.e., when the user selects a file to send), you can enqueue the work like this:

```
val uploadWorkRequest = OneOffWorkRequestBuilder<MediaUploadWorker>()
    .setInputData(workData) // If you need to pass data to the worker
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(uploadWorkRequest)
```

With WorkManager, the task will continue to execute even if the user navigates away from the activity or closes the application. The system will take care of running your task based on the conditions you specify, and will even respect battery optimizations.